# Is it possible to create variables based on the amount of arguments in a function?

Tags: c++

For example, I have a thread class with a template constructor which can take in an undefined amount of arguments:

```
template<typename _FunctionType, typename ... _ArgType>
thread(const _FunctionType* function, _ArgType ... arguments)
{
    _FunctionType Function1; // Creates variable for function
    _ArgType Argument1;      // Creates a variable for each argument given
    _ArgType Argument2;
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to create a variable for each argument given. If so, how could I do this?

Comment: Well, the closest that can easily come to that is an appropriate declaration for a `std::tuple`. However, this is certainly an XY problem. Suppose there's a way to do that, ***then what***? What are the plans after that? How are you planning to use an unspecified number of variables, in the rest of the function? How do you expect that to work?

Comment: Identifiers starting with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter are reserved for the compiler and standard library in all contexts. Do not declare them as template parameters or anything else.

Comment: What do you intend to do with these variables? A `std::thread` already internally makes copies of all passed arguments, so your thread class (which I assume is wrapping a `std::thread`) shouldn't need to store copies of arguments anywhere, if that is what you are trying to do.

Comment: @user17732522, templates can start with an underscore, its just bad practise to do so, but they are completely functional.

Comment: @user17732522, this is only an oversimplified scenario i have made up. In my actual project, i am storing these variables (for every thread) in lists for further use.

Comment: All I would like to know is if this is possible?

Comment: If its possible to get the amount of arguments in the parameter (for example `function.get_amount_of_arguments()`), it may be possible to create a variable for each argument given.

Comment: What does "i am storing these variables (for every thread) in lists for further use" mean?

Comment: _"templates can start with an underscore [...] they are completely functional"_ According to [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers#In_declarations) page, it's undefined behavior to have identifiers that start with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter (like yours). So, they're not functional at all.

Comment: On the underscore front, just as an example, an implementation could #define an underscore-followed-by-capital identifier that matches yours that completely screws up a template declaration for no apparent reason. "Don't do this" is right.

Comment: If you've seen a standard library implementation using reserved identifiers that would not be surprising... they are *reserved* for *it*. To conclude it's okay in general from that is a fallacy. "User space" programs risk nasal demons.

Comment: @anom How do you intent to store the values in a list? What type would the list have? As mentioned before `std::tuple<_FunctionType, _ArgType...>` can be used to store a heterogeneous list of objects, but how do you intent to use this tuple then? In what type of object do you want to store it? You would need to type-erase it and then have e.g. a `virtual` interface or something of that kind to access it. But without more information it is difficult to give a concrete recommendation.

Comment: @anom And as others have already said, using the identifiers has undefined behavior. That it happens to work for you does not mean that it is valid and it may fail on a different compiler or the next time you try to compile it with your compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write template specialization for functions with 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ... arguments but that defeats the purpose of having a template.

You can't really give each argument a unique name but you can put them into a `std::tuple`.

```
#include <tuple>

template<typename _FunctionType, typename ... _ArgType>
void thread(const _FunctionType* function, _ArgType ... arguments) {
    _FunctionType function_{function}; // Creates variable for function
    std::tuple<_ArgType...> arguments_{arguments...};
}
```